# Why is it necessary to call the OMSetRenderTargets DirectX method for every frame

Tags: c++, uwp, directx

I'm working on a Windows UWP app that contains a DirectX 11 view (inherits from Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::SwapChainPanel) that is implemented in C++. While optimizing the method that eventually renders the frame I came across a subtlety that I do not completely understand and for the life of me just cannot find any useful documentation (neither books nor online resources) that explains it.

So, my rendering method currently looks as follows

```
void Renderer::RenderFrame()
{
  _d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &_renderTargetView, _depthStencilView);
  _d3dContext->ClearRenderTargetView(_renderTargetView, reinterpret_cast<const float*>(&_backgroundColor));
  _d3dContext->ClearDepthStencilView(_depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);
  _d3dContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
  _d3dContext->DrawIndexed(_model->GetIndicesCount(), 0, 0);
}
```

Everything works fine so far, the model is properly rendered and everything looks as expected. While optimizing the code I figured that it should not be necessary to set the render target for every frame, i.e. calling OMSetRenderTargets should not be necessary for every frame.

My thought process basically is as follows:
The view instantiates the renderer and passes the renderer pointers to both the ID3D11RenderTargetView and ID3D11DepthStencilView. These are objects that are alive for as long as the view is and I *think* with the OMSetRenderTargets method I'm basically telling the system "hey, this is the render target view and stencil view you have to use". Why do I need to tell it this every frame? Shouldn't it just be "hey, use this render target view and stencil view until I tell you to use something else".

I was thinking that telling it once is enough which is why I have moved the call to OMSetRenderTargets into the method that the view calls to set the ID3D11RenderTargetView and ID3D11DepthStencilView which would then look as follows:

```
void Renderer::SetRenderTargetView(ID3D11RenderTargetView* renderTargetView, ID3D11DepthStencilView* depthStencilView)
{
  _renderTargetView = renderTargetView;
  _depthStencilView = depthStencilView;

  _d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &_renderTargetView, _depthStencilView);
}
```

The `RenderFrame` method would then look as follows:

```
void Renderer::RenderFrame()
{
  _d3dContext->ClearRenderTargetView(_renderTargetView, reinterpret_cast<const float*>(&_backgroundColor));
  _d3dContext->ClearDepthStencilView(_depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);
  _d3dContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
  _d3dContext->DrawIndexed(_model->GetIndicesCount(), 0, 0);
}
```

However, it is clearly not enough because if I do it that way there's nothing rendered anymore (except for the first frame probably, but that is all white so I'm not completely sure).

I'm sure that the fact that it does not properly render anymore is caused by the move of that method call because that is all that I'm changing here.

Does anyone have a clue why OMSetRenderTargets needs to be called for every frame? What else do I instruct the system to do by calling that method? Could someone point me to a piece of documentation that gives some insight?

Comment: As a note, I too noticed problems when moving to the flip model with my swap chain until I re-bound it each frame. This article says it's a requirement when using the flip model, if that is indeed what you are using: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/dxgi-flip-model/

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons that can cause the Rendertarget to be set to null.  The main reason I have found is in the documentation where if you are trying to read from a resource that is set to write (as in the rendertarget).  Without knowing the rest of your set up, if you are using copy resource or resolvesubresource then this maybe unbinding these texture from Render target.

[Direct X 11 - OMSetRenderTargetrs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476464(v=vs.85).aspx)

As you are using UWP, I would assume you are doing one or the other.  As such, you would be unbinding at that point.  You can use the GetRenderTargets call if you want to check the presence of your current rendertarget in OM.